# Knockout rate limiting with AJAX updates

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, knockout.js, rate-limiting

I'm trying to create an HTML form that updates some of its values based on what is selected in a dropdown.  The view model looks something like this:

```
function RoomViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.companyOptions = @Html.Raw({ ... });
    self.companyValue = ko.observable().extend({ rateLimit: 5000 });
    self.companyInfo = ko.observable();
    ko.computed(function() {
        if (self.companyValue()) {
            $.getJSON('@Html.GenerateActionLinkUrl("GetCompanyAndPlans")', {}, self.companyInfo);
        }
    });
}

ko.options.deferUpdates = true;
ko.applyBindings(new RoomViewModel());
```

I then bind my `select` dropdown to `companyValue`, and if I change the selection a bunch of times, only after 5 seconds does the `computed` kick in and display the currently-selected value.  This comes close to doing what I want, but the one problem is that the first time you change the dropdown, you shouldn't have to wait 5 seconds - it should make the JSON call immediately.  The rate limiting is to stop further JSON requests *in between* the first change and 5 seconds later.  So how can I make it immediately do the JSON request and update for the *first* change?

Comment: Here is a great article about Knockout's observable rate limiting: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html ~ Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ratelim = 0; // global rate limit 

function RoomViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.companyOptions = @Html.Raw({ ... });

    if(ratelim == 0){
      self.companyValue = ko.observable().extend({ rateLimit: ratelim }); // trigger the change without a delay 
      ratelim = 5000; // update the ratelim so the next request has a 5 second delay 
    } else { // ratelimit is not 0 (not first request), go ahead with regular rate-limited change: 
      self.companyValue = ko.observable().extend({ rateLimit: ratelim }); // extend the observable, with current ratelim
    }

    self.companyInfo = ko.observable();
    ko.computed(function() {
        if (self.companyValue()) {
            $.getJSON('@Html.GenerateActionLinkUrl("GetCompanyAndPlans")', {}, self.companyInfo);
        }
    });
}

ko.options.deferUpdates = true;
ko.applyBindings(new RoomViewModel());
```

I believe this should do the trick. I used a global variable (ratelim) to allow your function to detect whether it's the first request or not... Really you should be changing a variable value from true/false for whether a request is ongoing or not, so that there is 0 rate limit if the user has been 'idle' for a bit. Aka, if the 2nd request happens 20 seconds after the first, there's no need to still have a 5 second delay.

Comment: Huh???  How will this work?  It will just run once, during the construction of the new RoomViewModel.

Comment: Well, if you're only running it once then you would just need to update the ratelimit after the first time instead. {rateLimit: 0} should be default, and then you would need to update that to 5000 once it's been done once.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I started playing with it and the conclusion I reached was that you need a custom extender for this. [I found one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207677/custom-throttle-extender-in-knockout-js) which simulates the rateLimit and with some changes it does seem to address your need.

With this you should be able to do:

```
self.companyValue = ko.observable().extend({ customRateLimit: 5000 });
```

And have the initial change be instant and any subsequent be rate limited.

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akrion/xvmdqjLr/98/)

Here is the runnable code snippet:

```js
ko.extenders.customRateLimit = function(target, timeout) {
  var writeTimeoutInstance = null;
  var currentValue = target();
  var updateValueAgain = false;
  var interceptor;
  var isFirstTime = true

  if (ko.isComputed(target) && !ko.isWriteableObservable(target)) {
    interceptor = ko.observable().extend({
      customRateLimit: timeout
    });
    target.subscribe(interceptor);
    return interceptor;
  }

  return ko.dependentObservable({
    read: target,
    write: function(value) {
      var updateValue = function(value) {
        if (isFirstTime) {
          target(value);
          isFirstTime = false;
        } else {
          if (!writeTimeoutInstance) {
            writeTimeoutInstance = setTimeout(function() {
              writeTimeoutInstance = null;
              if (updateValueAgain) {
                updateValueAgain = false;
                updateValue(currentValue);
              }
              target(value);
            }, timeout);
          }
        }
      }
      currentValue = value;
      if (!writeTimeoutInstance)
        updateValue(currentValue);
      else
        updateValueAgain = true;
    }
  });
}

function AppViewModel() {
  this.text = ko.observable().extend({
    customRateLimit: 1000
  });
  this.rateLimited = ko.computed(this.text).extend({
    customRateLimit: 1000
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-debug.js"></script>

<h4>Change value is default so move the focus out of the input to change values.</h4>

<div>
  Enter Text: <input type='text' data-bind='value: text' />
</div>
<div>
  Rete Limited <small>(after the first change)</small>: <input type='text' data-bind='value: text' />
</div>
<div>
  Rete Limited Computed <small>(after the first change)</small>: <input type='text' data-bind='value: rateLimited' />
</div>
```

Notice after you enter text in the first text box how the change is immediate in the other ones. However any change **after the first one** is delayed

With this you can extend observables and computed observables.